# Firebase CloudFirestore reference datatype

Tags: javascript, firebase, types, reference, google-cloud-firestore

Does anyone know how the cloudfirestore reference datatype is supposed to be used ? I have a document that have a reference field, how do I get the referenced document when fetching the "parent" document and what is the datatype in JavaScript supposed to be for the field ?
Currently I am fetching again the referenced document which does not sound like a very good solution. Especially if you have a long list and for each document you need to re-fetch additional document(s). Is it possible to fetch all the documents in one get operation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference type fields come back in a query as [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) type objects on all platforms.  You can use it just like any DocumentReference that you build yourself.  This means, of course, you can call [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get) on it to obtain the contents of the referred document.